# Android Button Drawable Tint

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, uicolor

Is it possible to tint the drawableLeft in an android button? I have a black drawable I'd like to tint white. I know how to achieve this with an image view (image on the left) but I want to do this with the default android button.

[image]

My source code:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/drawer_quizzes"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_light_green_500"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_landscape"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        />
```

Is there any way to tint the button? Or is there a custom view method to achieve this effect?

Comment: so you want to place an image on the left of the text in the button?

Comment: @HawraaKhalil yes, exactly. But it should be tinted white

Comment: Vote here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198613 if you want drawableTint to go into support library

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can achieve coloring the drawableleft on a button with this method:

Step 1:
Create a drawable resource file with bitmap as parent element as shown below and name it
as `ic_action_landscape.xml` under the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
    android:tint="@color/white" />
```

Step 2:
Create your Button control in your layout as below

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_light_green_500"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_landscape"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="@string/drawer_quizzes"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
```

The button gets the drawable from the `ic_action_landscape.xml` from the drawable folder instead of @android:drawable or drawable png(s).

Method 2:
Step 1:
You can even add the icon as a Action Bar and Tab icons with Foreground as Image
that can be imported from a custom location or a Clipart

Step 2:
Under Theme dropdown select Custom

Step 3:
Then select the color as #FFFFFF in the Foreground color selection.
[image: Method 2 Pictorial representation]

Finally finish the wizard to add the image, then add the drawable as an image.

[image: Pictorial representation for answer to the question]

Comment: Thanks, i'm using the first method now as I'd also like to use the (black) icon in other parts of the ui.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that the tint attribute is only supported since Lollipop. For pre-Lollipop support, I used the following code to tint the button drawable programmatically: `Drawable[] drawables = postButton.getCompoundDrawables();
   Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawables[0]);
   DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));`, using the support-v4 library.

Comment: It seems method 1 only works for default icons(from android). If we add a new icon on our resources, it does not work on my end. Just a note.

Comment: android:backgroundTint="@color/md_light_green_500" its only above api level 23 not work in lolipop

Comment: This (method 1, in my case) also works if you want to change the drawable colour for a TextView.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing @AnandSavjani? Let me see if I can assist you and make my answer better.

Comment: I am trying to set drawable  tint but its now showing any tint effect

Comment: Thats nice hack. My app's minimum version is 21 so don't have to worry about below 21

Answer (score 14):

You can either use drawable filter or if your API>=M then you can simply

```
textView.compoundDrawableTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE)
```

or in XML,

```
android:drawableTint="@color/white"
```

Comment: android:drawableTint is the correct answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I know there are lots of answers already, but non of them made me happy since I didn't want to have different drawables for different styles of elements.

So my solution was to set color filter in constructor like this:

```java
int textColor = getTextColors().getColorForState(EMPTY_STATE_SET, Color.WHITE);
Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawablesRelative();
for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.setColorFilter(textColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
```

I used text color because this was what I need, but it can be replaced with custom attribute to be more dynamic.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to accomplish this same exact thing using a [MaterialButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) (from the material support library, which most people are probably using already). [MaterialButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) has an attribute named icon which can be placed left/center/right (default left). It also has an attribute called iconTint which will tint the icon.

Gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09"
```

View:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/drawer_quizzes"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/md_light_green_500"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_landscape"
    app:iconTint="@color/white"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Boris suggested, you can use the support library.

I have extended the AppCompatButton with some [draft code](https://github.com/snodnipper/android-appcompat-issue198613).  The [TintAppCompatButton](https://github.com/snodnipper/android-appcompat-issue198613/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/TintAppCompatButton.java) should have default behaviour *but*  [TintAppCompatButtonCustom](https://github.com/snodnipper/android-appcompat-issue198613/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/TintAppCompatButtonCustom.java) was made to demo custom coloring.

I’ll see if I can raise a PR to get that into the official support library.

The code of interest is:

```
private void init() {
    PorterDuff.Mode tintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN;
    Drawable[] ds = getCompoundDrawables();
    tint(ds[LEFT], Color.RED, tintMode);
    tint(ds[TOP], Color.YELLOW, tintMode);
    tint(ds[RIGHT], Color.GREEN, tintMode);
    tint(ds[BOTTOM], Color.BLUE, tintMode);
}

private void tint(Drawable d, int color, PorterDuff.Mode tintMode) {
    TintInfo ti = new TintInfo();
    ti.mTintMode = tintMode;
    ti.mTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);
    ti.mHasTintList = true;
    ti.mHasTintMode = true;

    TintManager.tintDrawable(d, ti, new int[]{0});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late on this but if you're using C#, you can do it this way:

```
Color iconColor = Color.Orange; // TODO: Get from settings
Mode mode = Mode.SrcAtop;

Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_action_arrest, null);

drawable.SetColorFilter(iconColor, mode);
```

You'll also need:

```
using Android.Graphics;
using static Android.Graphics.PorterDuff;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
```

Hope this helps.  It's the easiest way I found.
Note, too, that ANY place in your app that you are using this icon, it will be this color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:drawableTint="@color/yourColor"` in >23 android version.

Comment: what about below 23??

Comment: for that you can use app:drawableTint

Comment: Weird, doesn't work for me in API 23.

Comment: @KishanSolanki, here doens't work in API 23