# set drawabletint not work icon colour can't change android

Tags: android, xml

here is my xml code in this i was set a icon in left of textview and i want to change icon colour by use of drawableTint But its not work

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/signaturePadViewHeight_180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLogout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_logout"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/light_blue"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_15dp"
            android:text="Log Out"
            android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show me where this question ask and where is correct answer Man !!

Comment: [android:drawableTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#drawableTint) requires minimum API Level 23. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30946356/1771663) to add tint in API Level below 23