# Android TextView DrawableTint on pre v23 devices

Tags: android, textview, xml-drawable

Is there any way we can tint the `Drawable` used in the `TextView`? `DrawableTint` works only on API level 23 and above.

Currently I'm using a `Vertical Linear Layout` to achieve my requirement.

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/ChoiceIllustratorIconTextContainerStyle">

  <ImageView
    style="@style/ChoiceIllustratorImageStyle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_university"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_balance_white_24dp" />

  <TextView
    style="@style/ChoiceIllustratorTextStyle"
    android:text="@string/ci_text_university" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like,[image]

Android studio is suggesting me to use `Compound Drawble` with `TextView` to achieve this. And I'm able to achieve it, but I cannot find a way to `Tint` the drawable.

```
<TextView
   style="@style/ChoiceIllustratorTextStyle"
   android:drawablePadding="4dp"
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_account_balance_white_24dp"
   android:text="@string/ci_text_university" />
```

Comment: Can this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155463/drawable-tinting-for-api-21

Comment: I checked that, for my case its not helpful. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Button Drawable Tint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938620/android-button-drawable-tint)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

AndroidX appcompat library supports tinting in TextView since version 1.1.0-alpha03 <sup>[[ref](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha03)]</sup>.

Add dependencies to appcompat library

```
dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
}
```

Then drawable in TextView can be tinted from XML like this

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_plus"
  app:drawableTint="@color/red" />
```

Don't forget to include

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and to extend your Activity from `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: They should add this to the ctrl+space shortcut thingy

Answer (score 24):

The programmatic way to do this is

```
       Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
       if (drawables[0] != null) {  // left drawable
           drawables[0].setColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY);
       }
```

This works for all API levels.

This is your best option for pre-Marshmallow devices.

Comment: And if you need to use a different color on another screen or for different view states, I believe you would want to `mutate()` the drawable before call setColorFilter.

Comment: PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY does not work for me.
Instead, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP works for me.
Does PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY for you?

Comment: SRC_ATOP was what the OP settled on, so it's not surprising that it works for you too.  Can't remember exactly, but I think I might have been using a drawable with all-white pixels, so that MULTIPLY and SRC_ATOP would look pretty much the same.  The OP's method of using the compatibility classes is a better option as well.

Comment: for reference : drawable[0] left, drawable[1] top, drawable[2] right, drawable[3] bottom . Thanks this works.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Also note to use getCompoundDrawablesRelative for Start/Top/End/Bottom

Answer (score 15):

This answer is based on @kris larson suggestion.

I use the following methods and it is working fine on all devices.

`setTintedCompoundDrawable` a custom method that takes the `TextView` to which you would want to set the compound drawable, a drawable res id & and the res id of your color choice.

```
private void setTintedCompoundDrawable(TextView textView, int drawableRes, int tintRes) {
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            null,  // Left
            Utils.tintDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableRes),
                    ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), tintRes)), // Top
            null, // Right
            null); //Bottom
    // if you need any space between the icon and text.
    textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(12);
}
```

Tint `tintDrawable` method goes like this:

```
public static Drawable tintDrawable(Drawable drawable, int tint) {
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, tint);
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    return drawable;
}
```

Comment: call mutate() on the drawable loaded from resource id to get a separate drawable if you use the drawable resource somewhere else in the app with a different tint.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `TextViewCompat` class for this case:

```
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawableTintList(TextView, ColorStateList)
```

Comment: this won't work. This will always take effect when running on API v24 or newer

Comment: @YouQi Compat class is used, it means supports all the versions

Comment: You may want to read the doc of the function: `This will always take effect when running on API v24 or newer. When running on platforms previous to API v24, it will only take effect if textView implements the TintableCompoundDrawablesView interface.`
```. given the context of the question is below 24, your answer is not good enough as you didn't address the full caveat

Comment: Works great with `MaterialTextView` on API 21