# How to use drawableTint in button for api<23

Tags: android-layout, button

The icon color was shown in Android Studio but when running on mobile(android ver:19), the drawableTint color doesn't work.

[image: button]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_quiz"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent_layout"
    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_fast_forward_black_24dp"
    android:drawableTint="#11b4d1"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="Start Quiz"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Button Drawable Tint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938620/android-button-drawable-tint)

Comment: Thanks! it works.

Comment: <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_login_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_auth_email"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableTint="#9E9E9E"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="16sp"
               />
drawableTint not show any color changes