# drawableTint is not working through used AppCompact-v7:25.3.1

Tags: android, xml

This question is already exist in here. But I want to know this step by step.
I pasted the dependence in gradle under dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

and than what to do.
My xml code is here

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_not_working"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:paddingEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewGroup"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewGroup"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Drawable Tine not working"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/forword_arrow"
    android:drawableTint="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

this is the picture

[image]

The color of the forward_arrow is not changing.
There are several answer in here but want to know what to do step by step.
That's it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawable tinting for api <21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155463/drawable-tinting-for-api-21)

Comment: yes i saw that answers but could you please help me understanding this step by step? can i handle this by the xml file only without help of .java file?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin This is about tinting *compound drawables in a TextView*. This has nothing to do with image drawable tinting.

Comment: @EugenPechanec my mistake. It is possible to duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938620/android-button-drawable-tint  
This one should be closed
I  check comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025193/boris in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30946356/3166697
Problem can be resolved couple line code: `AppCompatButton b = findViewById(R.id.button_not_working);
        Drawable[] drawables = b.getCompoundDrawables();
        Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawables[2]);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));`

Answer (score 2):

Tinting compound drawables in TextView (and their descendants such as Button) was introduced in API 23 (Android 6) via `android:drawableTint` and `android:drawableTintMode` attributes.

As of today this feature was not yet backported to AppCompat support library.

---

Naturally I took an attempt at solving this myself. Check out the [appcompat-extra](https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons) library. It has the `XpAppCompatTextView` and `XpAppCompatButton` widgets. Your code may look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.XpAppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Drawable tint working"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    app:drawableEnd="@drawable/forword_arrow"
    app:drawableTint="?android:textColorPrimary"/>
```

Note that `android:drawablePadding` still uses the `android` prefix.

Layout preview of this widget may be broken. In such case add the following code so you at least know what the result app will look like:

```
    tools:drawableEnd="@drawable/forword_arrow"
    tools:drawableTint="?android:textColorPrimary"
```

To get the library put this in your *app module* build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/consp1racy/maven/' }
}

dependencies {    
    compile 'net.xpece.android:appcompat-extra:1.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You have to use the `tint` atttibute

EDIT: My mistake, it should be `backgroundTint`

Comment: `tint` is used for foreground image of ImageView and ImageButton. `backgroundTint` is used for background. `drawableTint` is for compound drawables of a TextView or Button. Also, there's a difference between `app:tint` and `android:tint` (same for other attributes). `app:tint` works as expected since support library 25.4.0.