# Can I set the colour of the Launcher Icon?

Tags: android, material-design

I am writing a very simple app as a starter and using a material design icon as the launcher icon. Is there a way I can set the colour of just the launcher icon like I can the size and shape?

Here is my code from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/gasstation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:iconTint="@color/sysGreen"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/gasstation"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The statement android:iconTint seems to be OK in that Android Studio has not flagged it as an error but it has no effect. The launcher icon is still the grey colour of the downloaded image resource.

Is this possible? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) to create the icon.

Comment: I have created a zip file and trying to load it. Thanks

Comment: Well somethings working - getting closer, no icon at all now. Perhaps I made a mistake in the import.

Comment: @Sam helped the most. Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you retrieve the icon from a drawable, basically a small image you have in your resources, you cannot change the color.
What you can instead do is to use the tool Image Asset Studio, here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

As explained

> In the Project window, select the Android view. Right-click the res
>   folder and select New > Image Asset.

then follow the guide..

Anyway from  API version 21, you can tint drawables,
as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938620/android-button-drawable-tint)

Comment: Thanks @trocchietto the first link is dead for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I finally did it as follows.

right click on res>new image asset>clip art>pick the icon

you can set the foreground colour manually in the Configure Image Asset screen